# Method not working in async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I used this: **getItemsPrice(appid, names, callback, [currency])** method outside async.waterfall, everything working but When I try do like this:

```
async.waterfall([
                function(callback) {
                    var w = inventory.map(function (e) { //parametr e przekazuje pojedynczy element tablicy
                        return e.market_hash_name;
                    });
                    callback(null, w);
                },
                function(w, callback) {

                    market.getItemsPrice(730, w, function(data) {

                        for(var i in names) {
                            console.log(names[i] + ' median price: ' + data[names[i]]['median_price']);
                        }
                        callback(null, 'three');
                    });

                },

            ], function (err, result) {

            });
```

In second callback array W has data, but market.ItemsPrice nothing return.

Comment: The first function doesn't seem to be async, is there a reason you're using a "waterfall" here ?

Comment: firstly I need to change inventory array to another, and then I have to pass this "another array" to market.getItemPrice. Is any async map functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need async here.

```
var w = inventory.map(function (e) { return e.market_hash_name; });
market.getItemsPrice(730, w, function(data) { 
 // DO SOMETHING HERE
});
```

1.inventory.map is not a asynchronous function.(or is it?).

2.market.getItemsPrice is the only function I can see here that is asynchronous. So just call it after the Array.map method is called and you should be fine.

3.In `market.getItemsPrice(730, w, function(data) ....`I see you are passing in 'w' for 'names', but in you example you iterate thru 'names' instead.

```
for(var i in names) {
   console.log(names[i] + ' median price: ' + data[names[i]]['median_price']);
}
```

Is that an oversight?

Let me know if I misunderstood you question.